# What controls the order of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations in a SQL MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

How does SQL Server's `MERGE` work?

If there are multiple operations to be performed (`INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`) then what controls the order in which these operations are carried out?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for `MERGE`? You specify within the syntax of your statement what actions should be taken under what conditions based on what match criteria. Have a read and try to do whatever you're trying to do, then come back if you have specific problems or questions.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> For every insert, update, or delete action specified in the MERGE
>   statement, SQL Server fires any corresponding AFTER triggers defined
>   on the target table, but does not guarantee on which action to fire
>   triggers first or last.

If I've understood the documentation correctly, SQL Server does not guarantee any order.  It will execute your query as it sees fit.

Comment: Isn't this quote referring to how SQL handles any triggers on target tables which have a `MERGE` executed on them, rather than how the `MERGE` itself handles `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s?

Comment: Yes it is, which is a good point.  I could not think of any other reason why the order would matter.  For most purposes, you can consider it as one operation.  But if your db contains a mess of spaghetti triggers *maybe* the execution order could be important.  In any case I think your comment, on the original question, is the better response.

Comment: "I could not think of any other reason why the order would matter."
One example is unique indexes: If the delete-part clears the room for the insert-part, the merge-statement will fail if Sqlserver decides to execute the insert first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for `MERGE` as per my comment.

Within a `MERGE` statement, you specify how to match records between the source and target tables and what actions to take when there is (or isn't) a match. This therefore determines what records are `INSERT`ed, which are `UPDATE`ed and which are `DELETE`d.

Take a look at the example from the above documentation page:

```
MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target  
    USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
    ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
    VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)  
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
```

Here, they are matching records on `target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode` and where there is a match, they update the target record with the `Name` value from the source. If there is not a match, they insert a new record into the target table using values from the source record.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It was about the order of operations. So the answer is: however SQL Server feels like it; there is no guaranteed order.